# Expectations and densities

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, expectation

Because of an article that I'm trying to understand, I've come up with the folowing question:

Suppose we have $f:(\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0})^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}  $ , $\ X,Y\geq 0  \ \ $  R.V.'s ; $X$ with density $g$

Is it ok this computation?

$$ \mathbb{E}(f(X,Y)) = \int_0^{+\infty}\mathbb{E}(f(x,Y)) \ \ g(x) \ dx $$

Comment: Do we have independent of $X,Y$?

Comment: @JohnZHANG indeed. The actual problem I'm dealing with is below, as a comment to your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X,Y$ are independent, then $dP_{XY}=dP_XdP_Y$, and by Tonelli's theorem (Fubini's theorem for non-negative functions),

$E(f(X,Y))=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} f(x,y)dP_{XY}=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x,y)dP_YdP_X=\int_{\mathbb{R}} E(f(x,Y))dP_X=\int_0^\infty E(f(x,Y))g(x)dx$

The conclusion doesn't hold for general $X,Y$.For example $X=Y$, $f(x,y)=xy$, then $LHS=(EX)^2$, but $RHS=(EX)^2$, which are not equal in general.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Actually, what I am working with is this:

$$E(e^{-\int_0^{T}{g(u) \mathcal{M}(du)}} )$$ where $T$ is an exponential R.V. and $ \mathcal{M} $ is the Poisson Random measure on $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$, independent of $T$; and supposedly 

$$E(e^{-\int_0^{T}{g(u) \mathcal{M}(du)}})= \int_0^{+\infty}{E(e^{-\int_0^{t}{g(u) \mathcal{M}(du)}}) g_{exp}(t) \ dt} $$

I thought I could write $E(e^{-\int_0^{T}{g(u) \mathcal{M}(du)}})$ as something like $f(T,X)$ where $X(\omega)= E(e^{-\int_0^{T}{g(u) \mathcal{M}_{\omega}(du)}})$, which is a R.V. ,but it's not working..

Comment: So far, I've written $\gamma : (\Omega ,\Sigma ,P) \rightarrow \ \Omega \times R_{\geq 0} \ : \ \gamma (\omega ) = (\omega , T(\omega ) )   $

Also $ X( \omega , t ) = \int_0^t{g(u) \mathcal{M}_{\omega }(du)}$

So $\int_0^T{g(u) \mathcal{M}(du)}$ would be $ X \circ \gamma $